# Sass failed to import using "~" from the node_modules folder

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm using Angular 6 to develop a single page web application, 
and I added the following [ngx-toast library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr) to my project.

when I added the following Sass into my project and when I used "~" instead of the relative path it failed to load the libraries:

```
   // regular style toast 
@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr.css';

// bootstrap style toast 
// or import a bootstrap 4 alert styled design (SASS ONLY) 
// should be after your bootstrap imports, it uses bs4 variables, mixins, functions 
@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';

// if you'd like to use it without importing all of bootstrap it requires 
@import '~bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '~ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';
```

but it's work when I'm using the relative path:

```
// regular style toast 
@import '../../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css';

// bootstrap style toast 
// or import a bootstrap 4 alert styled design (SASS ONLY) 
// should be after your bootstrap imports, it uses bs4 variables, mixins, functions 
@import '../../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';

// if you'd like to use it without importing all of bootstrap it requires 
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import'../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';
@import '../../node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr-bs4-alert';
```

my component modules

```
   @Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
```

of course that I can leave it like that, or just download the actual css from the manual, but it's bothering me that's it's fails to import since it should work.

any solutions?

Comment: did you try adding inside angular.json?

Comment: yes, and it work. 
also copy and paste the css and using the relative path. 
the only thing that does not work is using ~ in the import and I'm curious to understand why

Comment: ok, so its not blocking your development. You want to know why

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya yes, exactly  
Thanks

Comment: When creating a project, did you create by enable scss. 'ng new appName --style=scss'

Comment: Also '~' will make SASS refer to 'src/' folder. You can create 'ngx-toastr' inside src folder and place toastr.css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the SASS Docs, `~` will point to `src/` folder, when we import any SCSS files. We need to tell angular to include `node_modules/` path, when we import any sass file. This can be achieved using `stylePreprocessorOptions` property inside angular.json.

```
"styles": [
  ...
],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "../node_modules/ngx-toastr"
  ]
}
```